# Can't get DOMelement by using variable in my environment but in console i can

Tags: javascript, variables

My button in my websites have onclick for function addNewSetPlanningReskilling().

But I CAN'T get DOMelement by using variable in my environment, in console i CAN.

```
function addNewSetPlanningReskilling(){                                  
  numberOfSets++;
  console.log(numberOfSets); // here i have number as i want to have, for example 3,4,5..
  document.querySelector(`[data-key='${numberOfSets}']`).style.display = 'block';         
}
```

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null at addNewSetPlanningReskilling at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Comment: This works fine, you're going to need to provide more info if you want us to see your problem https://jsfiddle.net/gjntc2w0/

Comment: It means the element you try to find with `querySelector` does not exist. With what you have provided as info, that is all we can say. Possibly the code runs too soon, when the element is not there *yet* (maybe it is populated by asynchronous code, like ajax-based).

Comment: Thank you for answer. I understood this variable is null, because is runs too soon, when element is not there. Do you have way/method to change this?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for this :

change this :

```
document.querySelector(`[data-key='${numberOfSets}']`)
```

for this:

```
document.querySelector("[data-key='"+numberOfSets+"']")
```